# Order of ideals in Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to prove the following: Suppose $R$ is a Dedekind domain with quotient field $F$ and $I$ is an $R$ ideal. Define $\mathrm{ord}_P(I)=a$ where $a\geq 0$ is the largest power of the prime ideal $P$ dividing $I$. Then there exists an $\alpha\in F$ such that $\mathrm{ord}_P((\alpha))=\mathrm{ord}_P(I)$ for any prime $R$-ideal $P|I$.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I have a feeling that Chinese Remainder Theorem might be involved, but I'm not sure how to use it here. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $I=P_1^{n_1}\cdots P_r^{n_r}$, where all the $P_i$'s are distinct prime ideals and $n_i\geq 1$.

CRT gives a surjective ring morphism $R\to R/P_1^{n_1+1}\times\cdots\times R/P_r^{n_r+1}$.

Uniqueness of prime decomposition shows that $P_i^{n_i+1}\subsetneq P_i^{n_i}$. Pick $\alpha_i\in P_i^{n_i}\setminus P_i^{n_{i+1}}$. Let $\alpha\in R$ such that $\alpha\equiv \alpha_i \mod P_i^{n_i+1}$ (whose existence is given by CRT). Since $\alpha_i\notin P_i^{n_{i+1}}$, $\alpha\notin P_i^{n_{i+1}}$. Moreover, we have $\alpha=\alpha_i+(\alpha-\alpha_i)\in P_i^{n_{i}}$.
It follows that $\mathrm{ord}_{P_i}(\alpha)=n_i$ for all $i$, and we are done.